# How can I use default arguments in a method with python-fire?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-fire

I am having an issue with `python-fire` when a method has arguments with default values. Consider the following code:

```
import fire

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ''
        self.b = ''

    def methoda(self):
        self.a = 'A'
        return self

    def methodb(self, x='B123'):
        self.b = self.a + x
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = SomeClass()
    s.methodb().methoda()
    print(s.b) # this prints B123 correctly

    fire.Fire(SomeClass)
```

As seen in the comments, in the `print(s.b), it is printing`B123` correctly. But when i change the order of the methods being called in fire from the command line, I am getting the odd behavior.

Example:

```
> python x.py
B123 # correct

> python x.py methoda methodb
Here: B123
AB123 # both correct

> python x.py methodb --x B123 methoda
Here: B123
B123 # again both correct

> python x.py methodb methoda
Here: B123
methoda # this is not correct. It should print B123 here also
```

As you can see with the last example, if i call `methodb` (which has an argument with a default value), it prints `methoda` instead of `B123` as expected.

My question is, How can I use a method that has a default argument value first in this type of scenario without passing in `--x=something`?

In short, how can i make `> python x.py methodb methoda` properly print `B123`?

Comment: Looks like you need `--` or so otherwise the second string is interpreted as a positional argument to the method. What does the manual say?

Comment: Sadly, the manual doesnt really address this question. Nor does the examples. The usage of `--` seems odd considering the code works correctly when i do `methoda methodb`, but not when i do `methodb methoda`, but as seen by the print statement, it does work..

Comment: One method has a positional argument, the other doesn't

Comment: But the argument has a default value.. which is why `methoda methodb` works fine without passing a `--x=something`.

Comment: Yes, but the interpreter appears to be greedy

Comment: Haha. Yes, it does appear so. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, if it is a bug, or if this is an area for improvement on handling default args better in `fire`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd file an issue with the library devs. Worst case, you'll get an explanation. Best case they'll update the docs or fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `def methodb(self, x='B123'):` to `def methodb(self, *, x='B123'):`, which makes `x` a keyword only argument, so it can no longer be used as a positional argument. This way fire will use the default value.

There has also been a [github issue](https://github.com/google/python-fire/issues/207#issuecomment-554123385) discussing this.